# Can matlab's int8 function be replaced with faster alternative

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am using the matlab's `int8` function to convert a double to integer. However when my program runs for large number of values, it gives somewhat poor performance. For around 14 million executions this function cost approximately 3 minutes, and is by far the heaviest section of my program.

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this.

I will try some mathematical manipulations, and will update the question with other trials.

Here is the code fragment:

```
pixel_value = int8(pixel_value) + 1;
```

[image: performance screenshot]

Comment: You probably don't want to be looping over `x` and `y`. Can we see the whole code?

Comment: Have you tried using `hist` or `histc` on the H,S,V planes separately and writing to `histogram(curr_hist,1,:)` for example?

Comment: Not yet, but good idea. I can avoid looping over all the pixels, I'll try that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are just using `pixel_value` as an index into `histogram`, you can use `floor` instead of `int8` to truncate the decimal component in the same manner.

In your example you indicate positive values, but if you expect negative vales, then you can use `fix`.

But this doesn't seem faster...  hmm.

Comment: Wow! Actually that was a lot faster.
Now it takes only around 1.5 seconds. (Used `floor`)

Comment: Oh, that's good.  In my test it was almost the same for me.  Whatever works for you!